# CoinHive javascript doesn't seem to work

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, javascript, coin-hive

I recently made a localhost website to easily mine Monero using my home computers. With CoinHive and the JavaScript miner (without the opt-in screen), I don't see my processor usage go up at all, although, if I use the authedmine miner, the usage increases to 100%.

this is the code that I use to start the opt-in miner...

```
<script src="https://authedmine.com/lib/authedmine.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var miner = new CoinHive.Anonymous('PUBlIC KEY ENTERED HERE...', {
        throttle: 0,
    });
    miner.start();
</script>
```

When the code above is used, the website asks for mining permission and when pressed allow, it starts mining and the processor usage goes to 100%

```
<script src="https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var miner = new CoinHive.Anonymous('PUBLIC KEY ENTERED HERE...', {
        throttle: 0,
    });
    miner.start();
</script>
```

But when this code is entered, the only thing I changed is the link to the miner javascript location, the processor doesn't go to 100% utilisation and my CoinHive dashboard doesn't show a hash rate.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Any help or suggestions are warmly welcomed,
Thanks,

Sid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser might be blocking it, unfortunately some people abused this miner that is a great alternative to ads in my opinion however didn't inform users to this occurring leading to some browsers blocking the miner.

Source: https://www.wired.com/story/cryptojacking-cryptocurrency-mining-browser/

Archived link: https://web.archive.org/web/20171229133832/https://www.wired.com/story/cryptojacking-cryptocurrency-mining-browser/

Answer (score 0):

It is because you changed the link location. it uses authedmine, because you cannot use it as hidden. As the other person said, it was abused, so it can no longer be used with out notice to the user. Change it back to the authedmine and your set. You can still use all of the user and site coding to check user balance, withdraw and such. the Authedmine is just a go around so people cannot trick users into making them money.